# Step wise guide to install elementary OS on ryzen 5

Tags: system-installation, amd

Hey i am having an acer nitro 5 with ryzen 2500u i would like to how to install elementary OS on it cause the normal method using rufus doesn't work on it...i am not gr8 in installation of linux as i have always used only elementary os that too with an intel pentium which was direct install.
The normal way boots up the usb and shows the cores which do t respond within the time frame

Comment: Please add more relevant information to the question. For example, what causing the problem, add some error texts that you see on the screen etc. This helps people understand your situation properly and provide a better solution. Have a nice day 

Comment: Actually elementary os never installs with ryzen on its own..it need tweaking thats what i am asking for

Comment: did u find any solutions to it. I am also stuck and can't do it. I am trying to make my Lenovo Ryzen 5 with windows 10 dual boot with eOS but it fails at the boot screen.